# Blueimp gallery play-pause

Tags: javascript, html, blueimp

I use blueimp gallery for slideshow
For default when I open the slideshow it play pictures automatically, In other words it moves from one image to another automatically.

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
<div class="slides"></div>
<h3 class="title"></h3>
<a class="prev">‹</a>
<a class="next">›</a>
<a class="close">×</a>
<a class="play-pause"></a>
<ol class="indicator"></ol>
```

I want to stop playing images when I open the slideshow

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `startSlideshow` to `false` in [options](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#options) to stop auto scroll.

```
var options = {
    container: '#blueimp-video-carousel',
    startSlideshow: false, // set this to false to stop auto scroll
    // remaining options
}
```

or

you can pause the automatic slideshow using

```
gallery.pause();
```

check [api-methods](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#api-methods)

Comment: thanks it works, 
I put it like that instead in options ->
blueimp.Gallery(
     document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
     {
         container: '#blueimp-gallery',
         startSlideshow: false,
         carousel: true
     }
 );